# Customize Error Reporting using Structured Logs and Monitoring/Alerting on GCP

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions, google-cloud-stackdriver

I've added structured error reporting to my Google Cloud Function like mentioned here: https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/monitoring/logging#writing_structured_logs. I'm wondering if I can specify fields using this technique that I can then use in the markdown of the Alerting policy:https://cloud.google.com/monitoring/alerts/doc-variables?authuser=6#doc-vars. Based on the documentation at both of these links, I'm not sure if there's any overlap though both mention labels of some sort. Ideally I would just get the message that I specify and that shows up in the logs as that has a good amount of information.

Answer (score 1):

> **NOTE** [Error Reporting](https://cloud.google.com/error-reporting) is a distinct Google service. You **can** use it too with a Node.JS runtime on Cloud Functions.

Alerting is based upon Monitoring and you can create so-called [Log-based Metrics](https://cloud.google.com/logging/docs/logs-based-metrics) which are Monitoring metrics derived from Logs. Both permit labels. Log-based Metrics aggregate log entries and the labels are used as a dimension for the resulting metric.

So you can:

- Create Log-based Metrics from your (structured) logs using (some subset) of the log labels
- Create an Alerting policy on the Log-based Metric(s) using (some subset) of the labels in the documentation.

I was unaware of the Alerting policy documentation facility before your question but I'm confident you can get close to what you're after.

Comment: I tried to use Error Reporting at first, with the NodeJS library, but it wasn't causing the Alerts to go off. I'm able to get the Slack alerts to go off with the structured logs, but just unsure how to go about customizing the messages that come out of it based on the error.

Comment: @PhilippeSabourin did you get your error messages to show up in Error reporting at all?

Comment: I haven't looked back at it since then. My solution currently throws an error, which shows up in the logs, which then causes a Slack notification though with very few details. I plan to change it to directly post to slack when something goes wrong so I can get an idea of what's going on without having to go look at function logs.